# Error message on Canon Sureshot

Tags: canon, film, 35mm, error

I’ve just gone to use my Canon Sureshot zoom 70 for the first time, the film loaded ok and the flash seemed to be working but when I pressed the shutter button the picture didn’t take and an E came flashing up on the LCD panel.

When I then closed the lens cover the film wound on one time. Does this mean a picture was taken? Does anyone know what the error message might mean I’ve tried Googling it but nothing comes up.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Mike Butkus hosts the manual for the [Canon SureShot Z70W](https://www.butkus.org/chinon/canon_point_and_shoot/canon_pointandshoot.htm). If this isn't the exact same model, it sure looks pretty similar, so you can probably extrapolate the info in the manual to your camera. (Mike looks for a donation for hosting all these old manuals. I donated once.)

The manual says that when "E" is displayed on the LCD panel, this indicates a "self-diagnosis display when reset is necessary". The manual says to "open then close the lens cover" and "if the display remains, take the camera to be repaired".

Personally, I wouldn't trust a 25-year-old electronic point and shoot. Whatever about the price on release, these were predominantly cheaply-produced products. I think you'd have a much better experience with film photography by getting yourself a [SLR](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/87765) that allowed you to easily manually focus and set manual exposure. It would probably have a better lens than a point and shoot, and would allow you to be more creative and achieve better results. If you do want to keep it lo-fi, what about buying disposables? Or at least buy a camera that can be returned if it turns out not to be in good working order.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the lens is not fully extending per this webpage:

https://www.flickr.com/groups/536909@N23/discuss/72157628989814891/